# Is there significance to this frame from the season 2 opening?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Pictured are 6 members from the 104th training regimen, but they seem somewhat randomly selected.

[image: Members from the 104th training regimen]

At least, that is until:

> We find out that the two on the left are the armoured and colossal titans, and then Eren, who is also a titan, appears to be center-left.

Is there some significance or implication to this picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The significance is more than likely representing the lyrics of the song. When comparing the actual intro [here](https://youtu.be/LKP-vZvjbh8?t=52) and the translated lyrics [here](https://youtu.be/yW_MCSEAsiw?t=51), the lyrics during that moment of the intro are

> Dedicate! Dedicate! Dedicate your heart!